# Remove trailing zeros from string java

Tags: java

Although I have seen a question similar to this one asked quite a few times, I actually mean remove all trailing zeroes.

I would like to convert something like

```
"1903895810000"
```

to

```
"190389581"
```

I am looking for a String.replace() solution

Comment: Doesn't seem to me like you're looking for anything because this question has already been asked 1000 times before

Comment: Have you made any attempt at doing it using `replace()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple regexp with `replaceAll` will do it.

```
String s = "1903895810000";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("0+$", ""));
```

[EDIT]:

`s.replace(0, "")` will not work here, because it will remove all zeros from the string, so you can't use it. So, here I used `replaceAll`, that uses [regular expressions](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Regular_expression) to match replacement string. This simple regexp `0+$` matches any number of zeros `0+` followed by end-of-string `$`, so it would be "some zeroes at the end".

Comment: If you are going to answer such poor questions as this at least explain what your code is doing

Comment: But how? If OP couldn't write that regex, then an explanation of the regex is appropriate, so OP (and other readers) can learn something. This answer doesn't help much.

Comment: Added an explanation.